# Firebase Database : unable to delete the Firebase database Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to extract the value from list view to pass it in query line

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();


        Toast.makeText(Weekly_update.this,item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.delete:

                final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("R u sure??")
                        .setView(R.layout.custom_dialog_delete)
                        .create();

                dialog.show();

                Button b=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.cdb2);

                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {


                        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                        //i want to get the xxx from the listview when i press the screen
                        Query applesQuery = ref.child("WEEK WORK").orderByChild("date").equalTo("xxxxx");


                        applesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                    appleSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();


                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                Log.e("fail 123..", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                            }
                        });



                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }

                });
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You add the following code:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("question");
```

`keyValues.get(position)` gives me title of question

```
databaseReference.child(keyValues.get(position)).removeValue();
```